Who are Dhatri and Vidhatr?
In this chapter of Markandeya Purana, there was a mention of two deities, Dhatri and Vidhatr (Vidhatra or Vidhatri).

Those female sprites enter into a house and into clothing when they are reddened by sunset, and wherever the bali is not offered to Dhāṭri and Vidhātṛ at the proper time.

But, who are them? Is any details about them in scriptures?

They are described as sons of brahma in mahAbhArata Adiparva ch. LXVI :

"And Brahman had two other sons, viz., Dhatri and Vidhatri who stayed with Manu. Their sister is the auspicious Lakshmi having her
abode amid lotuses.


Well, do you provide some info about their worship method (inclubing the bali offering to them)?

viSNu purANa book 3 ch XI mentions worship - The residue of the oblation let him offer to the earth, to water, and to rain, in a pitcher at hand; and to Dhátri and Vidhátri at the doors of his house, and in the middle of it to Brahmá.
